# What is this electrical component called?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, connector, pins

I have this part in my lab that looks like a chip holder with pins. I tried googling that, but nothing comes up. I am interested in this part and I was wondering if it comes with a lid, but I need its name to do my research.

[image]

Comment: *I tried googling that, but nothing comes up.* - I just tried right-click on this image as it is and select "Search with Google Lens" (in Chrome) and it brought up hundreds of results, most of which are pretty accurate.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you might also be interested in [ZIF sockets](https://www.google.com/search?q=dip+zif+socket&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&oq=dip+zif+socket&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i15i22i30j0i10i15i22i30j0i22i30l2j0i390l2.3087j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). They don't have lids, but they do have levers!

Comment: @EugeneSh. But if you search for the text "chip holder" you get things for holding gambling chips XD

Comment: I would like informally call it like a break out connector for various 8 pad lga ic’s or such. Possibly while designing prototypes. Maybe like a prototyping 8 pin adapter or break out adapter. Another example would be like 144 pin one.

Comment: It’s a low insertion force DIP socket with ‘side wipe’ contacts for 8-pin DIP IC’s. Very common in the past and not very reliable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is a DIP (dual in-line pins) socket for through-hole 8-pin DIP packages.

If you search for "IC socket" you should find them at electronic component distributors.

Here is an example [TE Connectivity 8-pin socket at Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/8j4dht03).

Answer (score 13):

It's a dual-in-parallel (DIP) socket for an 8-pin IC in a through-hole package.

For decades, these were used on boards sometimes to allow ICs to be replaced or added later without any soldering. A board could either solder its ICs straight to the PCB or put them in sockets. The sockets increase the board cost so it was an important judgement. Most ICs weren't in sockets.

The type you have found ([shown on left](https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/spc15494/dip-socket-8pos-2row-2-54mm-th/dp/2668408?gclid=CjwKCAjwmJeYBhAwEiwAXlg0AVgzn7OXv8tFaYWeLMKicWxEQP3bDB6GD_02Y4Yjgx7xNXyF6RkDJRoCP-UQAvD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C2668408%7Cpgrid%7C%7Cptaid%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-SMART-PMAX-Medium_ROAS-Test915&gross_price=true)) uses a metal spring contact to hold the IC in place. These were the cheaper type. ICs had to be inserted and removed with great care, as their legs could easily bend when being pushed and pulled.

The more expensive IC sockets ([shown on right](https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/spc15525/dip-socket-8pos-2-54mm-th/dp/2678577?gclid=CjwKCAjwmJeYBhAwEiwAXlg0Ad6MNb7K8itEY_6g464prHhT258rDN9esjhFSoXuVT6DuZkAl4hGUxoCjsUQAvD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C2678577%7Cpgrid%7C%7Cptaid%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-SMART-PMAX-Medium_ROAS-Test915&gross_price=true)) use turned pins. These are much better quality and IC insertion and removal was much easier but still needed great care.

[image]  [image]

Instead of having a PCB made, boards for through-hole ICs could be knocked up using wire wrap or Verowire for the interconnections. IC sockets would be used for all ICs, [as shown below](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2013/09/13/wire-wrapping-the-nibbler-cpu/).

[image]

Comment: Yep. See NUMBER OF REMAINING PINS versus NUMBER OF SOCKET INSERTIONS here: https://www.baldengineer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/25120-bw.pdf. Yes, it's a joke, but that graph is realistic ツ

Comment: The Signetics WOM data sheet! Brings back memories. Thank you! So many sites on the web could benefit from its "FINO" (First In, Never Out) property.